# Show $\inf_{t> 0} f(tx)/x$ is well-defined.

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Let $V$ be a real vector space and $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function with $f(0) \geq 0$. I'm trying to show that

$$\forall v \in V:\inf_{t > 0} \frac{f(tv)}{t} > -\infty$$

Fix $v\in V$. We want to show that

$$\{\frac{f(tv)}{t}: t > 0\}$$

is bounded below.

I was not able to find a lower bound. I can find a lower bound for $1 \leq t <\infty$, but I'm still looking for a lower bound for $0 < t < 1$.

I think that $f(0) \geq 0$ will be crucial for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $v \in V$ and all $t > 0$ we have
$$
 0 \le f(0) = f\left( \frac{t}{t+1}(-v) + \frac{1}{t+1}(tv)\right)
\le \frac{t}{t+1} f(-v) + \frac{1}{t+1}(tv)
$$
which implies the lower bound
$$
 \frac{f(tv)}{t} \ge -f(-v)
$$
and therefore
$$
\inf_{t > 0} \frac{f(tv)}{t} \ge -f(-v) > - \infty \, .
$$

Comment: @user745578: That was indeed misleading and partially wrong. We can have $\lim_{t \to 0}  \frac{f(tv)}{t} = + \infty$ but of course $\inf_{t > 0} \frac{f(tv)}{t} \le f(v) < \infty$.

Comment: Thanks. The answer is perfect now!